# Not able to allow nginx to run on different port 3000 without opening the 3000 port in security group for everyone in EC2

Tags: nginx, amazon-ec2, webserver, nginx-reverse-proxy, aws-security-group

I am trying to run nginx for multiple server such that it listen port 80 and then revert traffic to 3000 for webserver1 and 3001 for webserver2.
I am able to achieve this process but issue is I need to open port 3000 and 3001 for all IP  which is not good for security purpose.
Can anyone please suggest steps so that my webserver listen 80 port and then divert to desired port according to configuration and we need to allow only port 80 in security group.

Comment: You're asking this at the wrong place. StackOverflow is for programming questions only. This belongs to either https://SuperUser.com or https://ServerFault.com